# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 Promise

Tags: javascript, php, promise, fetch

I'm trying to insert data from a form into a database. I try to do that with Fetch, so everything will be more dynamic.

This is my php file:

```
if (!empty($_POST['action'])) {
  if ($_POST['action'] == 'confirm') {
    $data =  array(
      'city_id' => $_GET['city_id'],
      'pub_id' => $_POST['pubs'],
      'beer_id' => $_POST['beers'],
      'snack_id' => $_POST['snacks'],
      'location_id' => $_POST['locations'],
      'daytime' => $_POST['daytime'],
      'participants' => $_POST['participants']
     );

  $insertedCrawl = $this->crawlsDAO->insertCrawl($data);
    if (!$insertedCrawl) {
      $errors = $this->crawlsDAO->validate($data);
      $this->set('errors', $errors);
    if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) == 'application/json') {
      header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array(
          'result' => 'error',
          'errors' => $errors
        ));
      exit();
    }

    $_SESSION['error'] = 'De crawl kon niet toegevoegd worden!';

    } else {
        if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) == 'application/json') {
          header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(array(
              'result' => 'ok',
              'crawl' => $insertedCrawl
           ));
        exit();
      }

      $_SESSION['info'] = 'De crawl is toegevoegd!';
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
      }
    }
  }
```

In Javascript I try to fetch this data to JSON.

This is my Javascript code:

```
const handleSubmitCrawlForm = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch($crawlForm.getAttribute("action"), {
    headers: new Headers({
    Accept: `application/json`
   }),
    method: "post",
    body: new FormData($crawlForm)
   })
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(data => handleLoadSubmit(data));
      };

const handleLoadSubmit = data => {
  const $errorText = document.querySelector(`.error`);
  $errorText.textContent = "";
    if (data.result === "ok") {
      loadCrawls();
     } else {
       if (data.errors.text) {
         $errorText.textContent = data.errors.text;
       }
     }
   };
```

Somehow I end up with this error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

It happens because I make a request to the server and parse the response as JSON, but it’s not JSON.

Comment: Does your FormData object set an `action` value, `$_POST['action']`? What happens if no action value is set?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your PHP file is returning something other than the json array you expect it to return.

One of the most common cultprit is trailing spaces or new lines after ?>, In case you have closed your php tags you might want to check for those.

You could also use the google chrome console -> Network tab to see the exact response your PHP provided which caused the JSOn validation fail.